# Creating a plot like picture with categories and dates

Tags: python, date, matplotlib, scatter-plot, linechart

I am wondering how I can make the following type of plot in Python (preferably matplotlib):

[image]

I would like four categories along the y-axis, and then the dates along the x-axis just as in the figure.

I have a CSV file with two columns [category], [date]. The date format is: dd-mm-yyy.

Extract:

category1,05-01-2020

category1,02-02-2020

category3,06-03-2020

category2,12-04-2020

etc...

Help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply plot the categories vs. the dates as is. For the color code, you need to convert the categories to individual numbers, which can be easily achieved using [pandas Categorical data type](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html).

```
d = """category1,05-01-2020
category1,02-02-2020
category3,06-03-2020
category2,12-04-2020"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(d), sep=',', parse_dates=[1], header=None, names=['category','date'])


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(df['date'],df['category'], marker='s', c=df['category'].astype('category').cat.codes, cmap='tab10')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for response. I have an issue with the xaxis. It displays all dates, but I would like it to only show dates at a certain interval. Example: Jan 2010, Jun 2010, Jan 2011, Jun 2011 etc

Comment: Also, how can I manually choose the color of the four categories?

Comment: For your first question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25538520/change-tick-frequency-on-x-time-not-number-frequency-in-matplotlib

Comment: For your second question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53360879/create-a-discrete-colorbar-in-matplotlib